# Add a new route with SailsJS

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm newbie with SailJS.

I want to create a new route, so I added this line in `config/routes.js`:

```
  'GET /operation/:operationId/sums': 'OperationController.getSums',
```

Then my function:

```
getSums: async function (req, res) {
    return res.status(200).json("OK");
  }
```

But I just get:

```
Forbidden
```

with a `403` status code. Other routes works well.

What can I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some middleware is rejecting this request. Try looking in your `config/policies.js` file.

It's possible there to set default permissions for all routes, or all routes for a given controller to `false`, ie, permit nobody (and in that case then you'd usually go in and override the defaults for particular routes).

Look for `'*': false` or `OperationController: { '*': false }`. If you don't see those, then try to see what routes *are* attached to your new route. Possibly, a custom created policy is rejecting the request.

Comment: Yep, it worked ! I'm justing working with sails so I'm not used to policies ! Thanks for your help